# Processing's curveVertex in Javascript

Tags: javascript, processing

I'm trying to replicate something in javascript that was originally written in processing and it uses curveVertex to draw. I don't really understand how curveVertex works, I tried to replicate it using quadraticCurveTo and bezierCurveTo but failed, so I'm looking for some help. I couldn't find anything useful via Google.

Here's the example code from http://processing.org/reference/curveVertex_.html

```
beginShape();
curveVertex(84,  91);
curveVertex(84,  91);
curveVertex(68,  19);
curveVertex(21,  17);
curveVertex(32, 100);
curveVertex(32, 100);
endShape();
```

If you could replicate something simple like this using Javascript, or point me in the right direction I would be very grateful. Thankyou.

Answer (score 0):

found it in the Processing.js source http://cloud.github.com/downloads/processing-js/processing-js/processing-1.4.1.js